# Flutter: No such module 'GoogleMaps' error in Xcode

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Every time I try to build the project using Xcode, I get the error `No such module 'GoogleMaps'`. Even though there are no errors, and maps work fine when the project is built via VSCode.

Package:

```
google_maps_flutter
```

AppDelegate:

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("MYAPIKEY")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

Info.plist

```
<key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
<true/>
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
#$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'
$FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.7.0'
platform :ios, '14.0'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'

project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def flutter_root
  generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), __FILE__)
  unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
  end

  File.foreach(generated_xcode_build_settings_path) do |line|
    matches = line.match(/FLUTTER_ROOT\=(.*)/)
    return matches[1].strip if matches
  end
  raise "FLUTTER_ROOT not found in #{generated_xcode_build_settings_path}. Try deleting Generated.xcconfig, then run flutter pub get"
end

require File.expand_path(File.join('packages', 'flutter_tools', 'bin', 'podhelper'), flutter_root)

flutter_ios_podfile_setup

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!

  flutter_install_all_ios_pods File.dirname(File.realpath(__FILE__))
end

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings["CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY"] = ""
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '14.0'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you have the same problem, but I was able to run a debug build and run on real device (and simulator), but not release, archive(release) or profile builds (they just wouldn't build!), but after doing some digging I found inside this folder: *your app name*/build/ios/, there are some folders:  Debug-iphoneos, Profile-iphoneos, and Release-iphoneos.  Within the Debug-iphoneos folder were about 49 items, of which were numerous folders which had: Firebase_Auth, GoogleMaps, etc.  When I looked into the other folders (Profile, Release) they only had about 5 items.  I decided to copy the contents of the Debug-phoneos (namely the folders) into the other folders and it worked!  I could build for any scenario without fail.

My concern is why the folders (Profile, Release) are not building properly?

I've cleaned, run, uninstalled, rebooted, used different devices and it didn't help.

Hope this helps anyone else who might be running into this situation.